# DataFrame not showing complete table data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I web-scraped some information about S&P 500 stocks from this website: https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500. The actual web-scraping bit works fine, as if I add a print statement after the for loop included, all data is displayed. In other words, the code:

```py
# Web-scraped S&P 500 data for 500+ US stocks.

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.62'}

url = 'https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500' # Data from SlickCharts
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

table1 = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-hover table-borderless table-sm'})

for row in table1.find_all('tr'):
    all_td_tags = row.find_all('td')
    if len(all_td_tags) > 0:
        company = all_td_tags[1].text
        symbol = all_td_tags[2].text
        weight = all_td_tags[3].text
        price = all_td_tags[4].text
        chg = all_td_tags[5].text
        perChg = all_td_tags[6].text
        print(company, '|', symbol, '|', weight, '|', price, '|', chg, '|', perChg)
```

Outputs:

```
Apple Inc. | AAPL | 6.866056 |    176.34 | 0.06 | (0.03%)
Microsoft Corporation | MSFT | 6.279809 |    334.50 | -0.19 | (-0.06%)
Amazon.com Inc. | AMZN | 3.729209 |    3,418.46 | -2.91 | (-0.09%)
Alphabet Inc. Class A | GOOGL | 2.208863 |    2,938.00 | -0.33 | (-0.01%)
Tesla Inc | TSLA | 2.169114 |    1,069.30 | 2.30 | (0.22%)
Alphabet Inc. Class C | GOOG | 2.056323 |    2,942.00 | -0.85 | (-0.03%)
Meta Platforms Inc. Class A | FB | 1.982391 |    336.00 | 0.76 | (0.23%)
NVIDIA Corporation | NVDA | 1.851853 |    295.60 | -0.80 | (-0.27%)
...
```

However, using DataFrame (I want to use it so I can search for data for a specific stock, example I type "AAPL" and I get the stock's price, weight, etc.), when writing this code:

```py
# Web-scraped S&P 500 data for 500+ US stocks.

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.62'}

url = 'https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500' # Data from SlickCharts
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

table1 = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-hover table-borderless table-sm'})

for row in table1.find_all('tr'):
    all_td_tags = row.find_all('td')
    if len(all_td_tags) > 0:
        company = all_td_tags[1].text
        symbol = all_td_tags[2].text
        weight = all_td_tags[3].text
        price = all_td_tags[4].text
        chg = all_td_tags[5].text
        perChg = all_td_tags[6].text

df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': [company], 'Symbol': [symbol], 'Weight': [weight], 'Price': [price], 'Change': [chg], 'Percent_Change': [perChg]})

print(df.head())
```

I only get the information for one stock, when I should get the entire table:

```
                    Company Symbol    Weight     Price Change Percent_Change
0  News Corporation Class B    NWS  0.006948     22.75   0.20        (0.89%)
```

Anything I did wrong with DataFrame so that it only displays that one stock (the stock displayed is coincidentally the last one in the table)?

**UPDATE**

I replaced the definition of `df` like so:

```py
# Web-scraped S&P 500 data for 500+ US stocks.

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.62'}

url = 'https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500' # Data from SlickCharts
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

table1 = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-hover table-borderless table-sm'})

for row in table1.find_all('tr'):
    all_td_tags = row.find_all('td')
    if len(all_td_tags) > 0:
        company = all_td_tags[1].text
        symbol = all_td_tags[2].text
        weight = all_td_tags[3].text
        price = all_td_tags[4].text
        chg = all_td_tags[5].text
        perChg = all_td_tags[6].text
        # print(company, '|', symbol, '|', weight, '|', price, '|', chg, '|', perChg)

df = pd.read_html(str(table1))[0]
print(df)
```

However my output looks something like this:

```
       #                    Company Symbol    Weight    Price   Chg     % Chg
0      1                 Apple Inc.   AAPL  6.866056   176.34  0.06   (0.03%)
1      2      Microsoft Corporation   MSFT  6.279809   334.50 -0.19  (-0.06%)
2      3            Amazon.com Inc.   AMZN  3.729209  3418.46 -2.91  (-0.09%)
3      4      Alphabet Inc. Class A  GOOGL  2.208863  2938.00 -0.33  (-0.01%)
4      5                  Tesla Inc   TSLA  2.169114  1069.30  2.30   (0.22%)
..   ...                        ...    ...       ...      ...   ...       ...
500  501     Discovery Inc. Class A  DISCA  0.009951    24.25 -0.17  (-0.70%)
501  502  Under Armour Inc. Class A    UAA  0.009792    20.62  0.00   (0.00%)
502  503                   Gap Inc.    GPS  0.008945    17.28  0.00   (0.00%)
503  504  Under Armour Inc. Class C     UA  0.008667    17.55  0.00   (0.00%)
504  505   News Corporation Class B    NWS  0.006948    22.75  0.20   (0.89%)
```

How do I make the second column of numbers disappear?

Comment: drop that column by index or name. Also, the ... just means not displayed for space reasons. The data is still present in the variable.

Comment: Hi @QHarr please excuse my ignorance for I am still fairly new with Python, moreover Pandas. I tried to do `del df.column.name` and `df.column.name = None` (similarly for `index` instead of `column`) but either nothing would change or I get an error stating that I can't delete the attribute. What would you suggest?

Comment: `df.drop(['#'], axis = 1, inplace = True)`

Comment: You can check the number of columns and rows with `print(df.shape)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you keep reassigning `company`, `symbol`, `weight`, etc. on each iteration, these variables only hold the values from the last row you parsed.

You can use `pd.read_html` instead. It returns a *list of data frames*, one for each `<table>` tag in the HTML snippet. There is only one table that you found through `soup.find` so it's element #0:

```py
df = pd.read_html(str(table1))[0]
```

Output:

```
 #               Company Symbol   Weight   Price   Chg    % Chg
 1            Apple Inc.   AAPL 6.866056  176.34  0.06  (0.03%)
 2 Microsoft Corporation   MSFT 6.279809  334.50 -0.19 (-0.06%)
 3       Amazon.com Inc.   AMZN 3.729209 3418.46 -2.91 (-0.09%)
 4 Alphabet Inc. Class A  GOOGL 2.208863 2938.00 -0.33 (-0.01%)
 5             Tesla Inc   TSLA 2.169114 1069.30  2.30  (0.22%)
...
```

Trim and rename the frame as needed.

Comment: Hi, so I made the necessary changes and you can see my output on my new edit, under UPDATE on the original post. How do I clear the second row of numbers? Furthermore, how can I see not just the top and bottom 5 entries, but all of them? Finally, I planned to use something like `df.loc[df['symbol'] == 'AAPL']` which in this case the output would be the row containing all of the Apple stock. However, because I'm not using DataFrame, is there any substitute? Thanks!